# Reading stdout from xinput test in python

Tags: python, linux, input, pipe, xorg

I am trying to stream the output of xinput into my python program, however my program just waits and stays blank. I think it may have something to do with buffering but I cannot say. Running `xinput test 15` gives me my mouse movements, but doing this will not print it. By the way, to find out your mouseid just type `xinput` and it will list your devices.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess


# connect to mouse
g = subprocess.Popen(["xinput", "test", str(mouse_id)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in g.stdout:
    print(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Are there any linebreaks in the output? What happens if you terminate the subprocess after a while? Does flushing `g.stdout` have an effect?

Comment: `xinput test` returns a new line for each event, 
And for terminate it just gives keyboardinterrupt

Aha, I think your change to `g.stdout.flush()` had an effect. It now outputs, wooha!

Comment: The only issue now is that it takes quite a few seconds to flush, meaning for testing I have to acquire hundreds if not thousands of lines until they all dump at once. Is there anyway to force immediate dump as soon as I can get it (there is no delay when command is run from console)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/index.html), specifically this tutorial http://amoffat.github.com/sh/tutorials/1-real_time_output.html

```
import sh
for line in sh.xinput("test", mouse_id, _iter=True):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me; however it looks like the `xinput` cmd buffers its output if not connected to a tty.  When running your code, keep moving the mouse and eventually `xinput` should flush stdout and you'll see your lines show up in chunks... at least i did when running your code.

I re-wrote your code to eliminate buffering, but I couldn't get it to not come out in chunks, hence why I believe `xinput` is to blame.  When not connected to a TTY, it doesn't flush the stdout buffer with each new event.  This can be verified with `xinput test 15 | cat`.  Moving your mouse will cause the data to print in buffered chunks; just like your code.

My test code is below if helpful

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

# the -u flag makes python not buffer stdios


import os
from subprocess import Popen

_read, _write = os.pipe()

# I tried os.fork() to see if buffering was happening
# in subprocess, but it isn't

#if not os.fork():
#    os.close(_read)
#    os.close(1) # stdout
#    os.dup2(_write, 1)
#
#    os.execlp('xinput', 'xinput', 'test', '11')
#    os._exit(0) # Should never get eval'd

write_fd = os.fdopen(_write, 'w', 0)
proc = Popen(['xinput', 'test', '11'], stdout = write_fd)

os.close(_write)

# when using os.read() there is no readline method
# i made a generator
def read_line():
    line = []
    while True:
        c = os.read(_read, 1)
        if not c: raise StopIteration
        if c == '\n':
            yield "".join(line)
            line = []
            continue
        line += c



readline = read_line()

for each in readline:
    print each
```