# subprocess.Popen: how to terminate subprocess and receive its output?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I want to run a shell command from python and receive its output with subprocess.Popen. The problem is, when I close the process, sending Ctrl-C, I don't get any output. What am I doing wrong? Code:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> sub = subprocess.Popen(["xinput", "test", "8"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #receive mouse events
>>> output = sub.communicate()[0].read()
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 693, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'output' is not defined
```

Inspired by this post by Jett:

[Reading stdout from xinput test in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420999/reading-stdout-from-xinput-test-in-python)

Comment: What happens is that you execute a **python statement**, then terminate it from the command line by ctrl+C, what means that output doesn't get assigned because an exception get raised, therefore output is not assigned and you get NameError. close the process without terminating the python statement, via kill or something else

Comment: @pythonm -- or terminate it via any Exception for that matter.

Comment: @Bob, one thing to keep in mind with xinput is if you start reading data from test it will be buffered, so you will only get chunks of it, http://empty.sourceforge.net/ is a possible solution as faking a TTY seems to need to be the case for realtime output.

Comment: @jett Thank you, but I'm not sure, I understand, what you mean, when speaking of bufferization. Who buffers data and why I'll get only chunks of it? Why would I need to fake a TTY? You suggest using `pexpect` module? – Bob

Comment: `xinput test` seems to only output data in realtime if connected to a TTY, otherwise it stores up it's output into a buffer and outputs it after the buffer gets filled. Here is a response for further info. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12426921/778858

Comment: @jett Ah, you meant, that `subprocess` doesn't read any data from a stream, opened by `Popen` before that stream is closed or buffer is filled or he's explicitly asked to `flush`? But at least those `chunks` are complete, right, so no info is lost, if buffer is filled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the `KeyboardInterrupt` is sent during the call to `communicate`.  As a result, `communicate` never returns and so it's output is never stored in the variable `output` and you get the `NameError` when you try to use it.  One workaround would be the following:

```
 import subprocess
 sub = subprocess.Popen(["xinput", "test", "8"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 lines = [] #Need someplace to store the data as it comes
 try:
    for line in sub.stdout: #read one line from standard out, store it in lines
        lines.append(line)
 except KeyboardInterrupt:  #keyboardInterrupt happened.  Stop process
    sub.terminate()
 finally:                   #Join our lines into a single buffer (like `communicate`)
    output = ''.join(lines)
    del lines               #clean `lines` out of our namespace (just because).
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Not going to mix complex actions in one line any more.

Answer (score 2):

@pythonm already explained the `NameError`.

Furthermore, you're using the output of `Popen.communicate()` conceptually wrong. It returns a 2-tuple of strings: `(stdout, stderr)`. It does not return two file-like objects. That's why your `sub.communicate()[0].read()` would fail if `communicate()` returned.

Until the subprocess returns, `communicate()` aggregates all of its stdout and stderr (considering that you provided `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to the constructor). Only after the subprocess has terminated, you have access to what `communicate()` collected during the runtime of the subprocess.

If you would like to monitor a subprocess' output in real time, then `communicate()` is the wrong method. Run the subprocess, monitor it (within for example a loop) and interact with its `Popen.stdout` and `Popen.stderr` attributes (which are file-like objects then). @mgilson's answer shows you one way how to do it :)

Comment: Thanks, Jan-Philip. It was quite deceiving idea of "subprocess" authors to name the arguments and output of "communicate" stdout/stderr/stdin, although they are str's in fact. Impatient readers like me get caught. :)